# Sort Collection by Date and Time

Tags: arrays, laravel, sorting, object

I have got a laravel Collection that looks as follows:

```
$data::where('name','xyz')->get();
//Returns {"id":"1" , "date":"11.11.2011"...}
{"id":"2","date":"12.11.2011"...}
```

and what I now want is : Sort these entries by Date AND time
So there are multiple entries per date.
So i thought about splitting every entry with the same date into one array , sort them, and merge them afterwards.
but i cant get it to work at all. i could post some code here now but that is all wrong and would lead your mind in the wrong direction i believe.
the problem is, that the entries are Objects and i have problems comparing.
Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

basically what I did now thanks to @Rafael Renan Pacheco was :

```
$sorted = $data->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
        return $product->date;
    });

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($sorted as $sort) {
        var_dump($sort->date);
    }
    echo '</pre>';
```

which results in :

```
string(10) "2019-11-08"
string(10) "2019-11-08"
string(10) "2019-11-08"
string(10) "2019-11-09"
```

so this is good. But how do i sort by the second key, which is in my case "deptime" which returns hours minutes and seconds?
So first ordering by date , completed. Now ordering this one by Time without rearranging the dates (except for the same day).
I mean i can also update my table so that i have a date with 2019-11-09 17:24:00 or something. Any ideas?

Comment: Produce a few records from your array and show the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take at look at this example from [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-sortby) which allows a callback to determine the ordering:

```php
$sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
    return count($product['colors']);
});
```

In your case you would compare the date AND time from each row, resulting in a new and sorted collection.

Comment: @Coderz9 There is no time mentioned . Is the "date" attribute timestamp?

Comment: i think i got it working, deptime is the time in its own field. i got this now :         $sorted = Data::where('pic', 'HST')->orWhere('pic', 'BAL')->orderBy('date','asc')->orderBy('deptime','asc')->get();
which returns the correct result, i am afraid even thought if it did not happen yet, that the second orderby overwrites the first. what do you think ?

Comment: Dump the sql for this request to make sure "date asc" comes before "deptime asc". In SQL, the first order by takes priority over the second, and so on. If "date asc" comes first, then it should take priority over "deptime asc".